# Laravel show single post if clicked on title

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to make a blog with posts, when the title of the posts are clicked on the single post should be displayed. But when I now click on a title I get a 404 not found error. Im sorry in advance for mistakes made on my part, im new to using laravel.

PostController

```js
/**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $name = 'Mijn posts';
        //get data from the te model
        $posts = Posts::all();
        //dd($posts);

        return view('posts.index', compact('name', 'posts'));
    }

    public function show(Post $slug)
    {
        return view('posts.post', ['post' => $slug]);
    }
}
```

web.php

```js
Route::get('/posts', [\App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/posts/{slug}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
```

Post.blade

```js
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('showpost')

    <div>
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <h1> {{ $post->title }} </h1>
            <p> {{ $post->body }} </p>
        @endforeach
    </div>

@endsection
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what URL you get when 404 error?

Comment: Have you tried [using this method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name). Laravel is not able to guess what Eloquent model you are trying to fetch.

Comment: why are you using UserController for doing operations of posts? it is not something illegal but it is against convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First you need to add a route name:**

```
Route::get('/posts/{slug}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('post.show');
```

**Second you need to change** `<h1> to <a href="{{route('post.show',$post)}}">`

Comment: When I do this I  get: InvalidArgumentException
View [user.profile] not found.

Answer (score 0):

Route model binding did't get the slug
If you try this way it will be done

PostController

```
     /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

public function index()
{
    $name = 'Mijn posts';
    //get data from the te model
    $posts = Posts::all();
    //dd($posts);

    return view('posts.index', compact('name', 'posts'));
}

public function show($slug)
{
    $slug = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('posts.post', ['post' => $slug]);
}
```

Comment: this does not fix my problem im afraid

Comment: Why not ? I checked it and gave it to you

Comment: I  get the same error